# php5-fpm - RecursiveIteratorIterator & RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Tags: php, ubuntu, recursion, nginx, laravel-4

I have a script that I want to create an array of all files and folders within a specific directory.

However, I have a problem. This setup worked perfectly on an Apache2 + php5 installation but I recently switched over to nginx + php5-fpm and now this script does not work.

The RecursiveIterator function is called without any errors but returns an empty array.

```
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($this->path));

var_dump($files);
die;
```

The error it outputs is:

```
object(RecursiveIteratorIterator)#218 (0) { }
```

I've looked around and there's no answer for this. Does my setup require another package to be installed?

Comment: And `$this->path` contains a valid path?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen The string set for this is: `storage_path().'/uploads';`

The inside of this folder has these 4 folders:

`backups
originals
sqldumps
thumbnails`

Comment: That is not what I asked. What is the *actual value* of `$this->path`?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Like I said...

`$this->path = storage_path() . '/uploads';`

Which would be `/var/www/domain.com/app/storage/uploads`

Comment: `storage_path()` is not a PHP function, so there is no way for us to know what it returns. I know this may sound stupid, but does that path actually exist? If so, does it contain anything? It would be a waste of everyone's time if it does not exist or if it is empty...

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen It is an existing function that Laravel 4.2 provides.

Comment: Maybe you can check by writing hard coded path rather then using a value.

Comment: What is the output if you add `echo(storage_path() . '/uploads');`